# How to convert the below date format into standard date format in R?

Tags: r

I have below date and time values in dataframe, some values are in "/" format and some are in "-" format. How should I standardize the format and keep it "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS". Also in time in some cases seconds values are not there.
Any suggestions ?

```
Datime$Day
11/7/2016 11:51
11/7/2016 17:57
12/7/2016 9:17
12/7/2016 21:08
13-07-2016 08:33:16
13-07-2016 21:57:28
14-07-2016 06:15:32
15-07-2016 05:11:52
15-07-2016 17:57:27
```

Comment: Is it correct that these are strings? Does `class(Datime$Day)` return "character"?

Comment: it's a "character" class.

Comment: You could use `gsub("/", "-", Datime$Day)`

Answer (score 2):

One option is `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` to match multiple patterns and convert it to a datetime class

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(Datime$Day, c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
#[1] "2016-07-11 11:51:00 UTC" "2016-07-11 17:57:00 UTC"
#[3] "2016-07-12 09:17:00 UTC" "2016-07-12 21:08:00 UTC"
#[5] "2016-07-13 08:33:16 UTC" "2016-07-13 21:57:28 UTC"
#[7] "2016-07-14 06:15:32 UTC" "2016-07-15 05:11:52 UTC"
#[9] "2016-07-15 17:57:27 UTC"
```

---

Another option is `anytime` (if the formats are not already found in the default format list `getFormats()`, add the new format with `addFormats()`)

```
library(anytime)
addFormats( c("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
anytime(Datime$Day)
```

#### data

```
Datime <- structure(list(Day = c("11/7/2016 11:51", "11/7/2016 17:57", 
"12/7/2016 9:17", "12/7/2016 21:08", "13-07-2016 08:33:16", 
   "13-07-2016 21:57:28", 
"14-07-2016 06:15:32", "15-07-2016 05:11:52", "15-07-2016 17:57:27"
)), .Names = "Day", 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Akrun for your kind help. It's working properly.

Comment: @SurajKumarTalreja  If this answered your question,  please upvote and accept the answer (checkmark at top).

Comment: Yes @SurajKumarTalreja, rather than thanks, you should **accept it**. Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

using the base library:

```
strptime(paste0(gsub("/","-",Datime$Day),":00"),"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S","UTC") 
[1] "2016-07-11 11:51:00 UTC" "2016-07-11 17:57:00 UTC"
[3] "2016-07-12 09:17:00 UTC" "2016-07-12 21:08:00 UTC"
[5] "2016-07-13 08:33:16 UTC" "2016-07-13 21:57:28 UTC"
[7] "2016-07-14 06:15:32 UTC" "2016-07-15 05:11:52 UTC"
[9] "2016-07-15 17:57:27 UTC"
```